# How to get users/usergroups from an lookup column from SPField

Tags: lookup-column, groups, user, membership

I have a custom list for example "MyCustomListA"
I have created a custom ListForm template and overide the ListFieldIterator. I have overide the ListFieldIterator and CreateChildControls to implement some readonly logica depandant of user membership.

One of the fields is a lookup to another custom list (MyCustomListB). In this custom list I am using a custom content type with 2 fields:

(MyCustomListB)

1: Title

2: Person or Group

The lookup shows a dropdownlist with for each item in "MyCustomListB" only the title. I would like to get the "Person or Group" value, someone know how??

```
public class CustomListFieldIterator : ListFieldIterator
{

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
    // some logic to set readonly depandant by user membership    
    }

    protected override bool IsFieldExcluded(SPField field)
    {
                  // some logic
                  if(field.InternalName.Equals("UsersAndGroups"))
                    {
                        // get users and groups from this field
                        SPUser selectedUsers = field.Some logic...
                        SPGroup selectedUserGroups = field.Some logic...
                        // some logic
                    }

    }

}
```

Comment: in which moment do you want to get this value, after user pressed "Save" in new\edit form?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you:

```
SPFieldUser userField = (SPFieldUser)item.Fields.GetField("UsersAndGroups");
SPFieldUserValue userFieldValue = (SPFieldUserValue)userField.GetFieldValue(item["UsersAndGroups"].ToString());
SPUser user = userFieldValue.User;
```

If you want more examples (e.g. when using multi-value selections) see here http://dsen-25.blogspot.ch/2012/07/how-to-get-spuser-or-spgroup-from.html

[EDIT after Comments]: If the UserAndGroups column is actually pointing to another list having one column of type "Person or Group" you need to use something like expressed here [Get related items from a parent list item through lookup](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18022/get-related-items-from-a-parent-list-item-through-lookup)

Comment: Thanks for your support.. what do I need to fill in as currentValue?? Is it the column name from MyCustomListB?

Comment: updated code with a piece from the article adapted to your case

Comment: I dont have an item object in my code. How can I get current item in the IsFieldExcluded method?

Comment: but you do, using this.Item as you are using the ListFieldIterator class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listfielditerator_properties.aspx

Comment: are we talking about SPItem or SPListItem?

Comment: SPItem is actually the parent of the SPListItem. Use the SPListItem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7464/discussion-between-kha-and-c-marius)

Comment: above peace of code is not working, because the field with title "UsersAndGroups" is a lookup field to a custom list. In this custom list there are 2 fields: "Title" and "Person or Group". So I need first some reference to the lookup field "UsersAndGroups", after this I need to get value of field "Person or Group".

Comment: didn't really get it from your comments as such and I assume, that actually you have a lookup pointing to another list, which also contains the UserAndGroups column. You need to treat a little different than - i've updated my answer.