# Create a user group from a SharePoint list item people or group

Tags: visual-studio, groups, sharepoint-list

I am trying to create a user group from a item in a SharePoint list. The list has a column `person` that is typed as person or group. In the event handler I am trying to take this column and create a group from the people in that list item. I know how to create a group using the method

> public void EnsureSPGroup(string spGroup, string spGroupOwner, string SiteURL)

And I know how to add users with

> public void AddUser(String userLoginName, int groupID, string SiteURL)

What I'm not sure how to do is create this group with users from the list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to loop the person column:

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection objUserFieldValueCol = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(web, listitem["UserGroupField"].ToString());
for (int i = 0; i < objUserFieldValueCol.Count; i++)
{
    SPFieldUserValue singlevalue = objUserFieldValueCol[i];
    if (singlevalue.User == null) // value is a SharePoint group if User is null
    {
        SPGroup group = web.Groups[singlevalue.LookupValue];
        foreach (SPUser user in group.Users)
        {
            //do stuff with the user
        }
    }
    else // singlevalue.User value is a user
    {
        //do stuff for the singlevalue.User
    }
}
```

Source: [How to retrieve Users and Groups seperately from a "Person or Group" column via C# code?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62606/how-to-retrieve-users-and-groups-seperately-from-a-person-or-group-column-via)

Comment: I'm not trying to loop the whole column just create the group from one item in the list. However, I think `SPFieldUserValuCollection` should lead me to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharepoint designer site workflows to create sp group. Need to write custom activity 
Please refer this 
http://www.jrjlee.com/2014/01/custom-workflow-activity-for-creating_23.html?m=1